# Is it possible to combine two Excel spreadsheets with different rows and columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is difficult to explain but I basically have two spreadsheets of data which I need to combine for research. The surveys have been conducted in two different ways so the columns and rows are reversed but I need to combine them. Is there a way that I can move the data in sheet 2 to look like the data in sheet 1 without doing it manually?

I have tried to use a pivot table but I could not get this to display the data I need.

Sheet 1

```
          Dog   Cat Mouse
Person A    1   3   3
Person B    3   2   3
Person C    2   1   2
```

Sheet 2

```
              1    2     3
Person A    Dog    Cat  Mouse
Person B    Cat    Dog  Mouse
Person C    Cat    Dog  Mouse
```

I expect the table in sheet 2 to look like sheet 1 however I cannot find a formula or method of doing this.

Comment: That would require some coding or at least some really smart array formulas.

Comment: If you can provide the list of persons and the title row SUMPRODUCT will do the counting.

Comment: Or do you want to return the `1`,`2`, or `3` depending on where the animal is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the people list and the possible outcomes, then use this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(G$1,INDEX($B:$D,MATCH($F2,$A:$A,0),0),0))
```

Which uses the list of people and the outcomes above to return the correct number from the first table.

[image]